# Too long text in LinearLayout pushes off ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

At the end of a `LinearLayout` there is an `ImageView` separated by a `Space` from the `TextView`. When the text in the `TextView` isn't too long, the `ImageView` appears nicely right-aligned. But when the text is too long, it eats up the hole of the `LinearLayout` and the `ImageView` is pushed off.

How can I avoid this? I would like the text to get ellipsized just before the `ImageView` so that the `ImageView` is always visible.

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_gold_24dp"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to set the weight on the TextView so that it fills all available space. Can you try something like this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        tools:text="This is some really long sample text"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_gold_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageView` with fix size and `TextView` with weight like this -

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_gold_24dp"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to solve this problem:

1. Set weight to your `TextView`, optionally set fix width for `Space`, and optionally set fix width, height for `ImageView`

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="20sp"
       tools:text="This is some really long sample text"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:textSize="20sp" />

   <Space
       android:layout_width="20dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="20sp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
   ```
2. Replace your `LinearLayout` with `ConstraintLayout`, and use `Barrier` to limit the width of your `TextView`.

Check this [awesome page](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html) for how to use Barrier in ConstraintLayout

To get familiar with ConstraintLayout, you can check this codelab [Using ConstraintLayout](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0)